# Are the UPlay rewards for MMX balanced?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

Did anyone unlock the rewards for Might and Magic X yet and can say if they are in balance with the rest of the game? Unfortunately UPlay tends to do very overpowered rewards for games like that, which have the potential to destroy the experience. While I do  not mind some small startup help, especially since I plan playing on Warrior, I'd hate to be OP right from the start of the game. But if unlock it, I also want to use, so that is a 2 sided sword.

[image: rewards screenshot]

Can anyone who already unlocked them tell how they hold up compared to other items/hirelings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unlocked the Special Relic Set using points I earned from other games, but as I'm not far into MMX yet, I can't tell you exactly how they compare.  Here is what I can tell you:

1) It looks like you need to start a new game for them to show up in your inventory.  If there is another way to get them to show up, I don't know what it is.

2) Each item is unidentified when you receive it and each one costs 150 gold to identify.

3) Three of the four items require that you be Expert in a particular skill, so even if you get it identified you can't use it right away.

4) Each item can level.

The Hacker (2-handed axe)
Level 1 (0/800 xp)
30-40 dmg
30% crit dmg
Requires Expert Axe and Novice 2-handed

Thunderstaff (staff)
Level 1 (0/1050 xp)
18-20 dmg
22% crit magical dmg
Requires Expert Magical Focus

Craig Hack's Helmet (headgear)
Level 1 (0/1055 xp)
3 armour value

Unbreakable (medium armour)
Level 1 (0/1150 xp)
15 armour value
-30 attack value
Requires Expert Medium Armour

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are relics would be added in inventory only once? Or you will get it in every new game?

Comment: You will get them every time you start a new game.

Comment: According to http://uplay.ubi.com/en-GB/news/might-magic-x-legacy-uplay-actions-rewards: *Unlock a special Relic set that will automatically be added to your inventory, even if you are already in the middle of an adventure!*   the items do appear in my inventory after autosaving, so there's no need to start a new game

Answer (score 0):

They are decent items, but I'm already replacing them.  They seem to stop leveling up at 4.
Once you get to just after the Crag, you'll be replacing them.  Either with random drop items or other relics.